# Рекурсия в python классах

Tags: python, классы, рекурсия

Есть код:

```
class Bank:

    def __init__(self, N, R):
        Month = 12 * R

        def deposit(n, month):
            if month == 0:
                return n
            return deposit(n, month - 1) * (1 + 10 / 100 / 12)

        profit = deposit(N, Month)
        print(f'Сумма на счету к концу срока: {profit}')


Bank(14, 10)
```

Рекурсия работает нормально
При попытке улучшить программу с добавлением нового класс все ломается:

```
class Investment:

    def __init__(self, N, R):
        self.N = N
        self.R = R
        self.Month = 12 * self.R


class Bank:

    def deposit(self, investment):
        if investment.Month == 0:
            return investment.N
        return investment.N + (investment.Month - 1) * (1 + 10 / 100 / 12)


vklad = Investment(14, 10)
bank = Bank()
print(bank.deposit(vklad))
```

Скажите, как правильно перенести рекурсию?

Comment: По логике у вас должна остаться рекурсия, но рекурсии у вас во втором варианте нет. Чтобы считало как раньше, должна или остаться рекурсия, или появиться цикл (или появиться формула со степенями для вычисления сложного процента).

Comment: Да, я понимаю что рекурсии уже нет, как мне ее вернуть во второй вариант? В этом мой вопрос

Comment: Ну была же рекурсия. Нужно было просто заменить имена переменных. Зачем функцию-то изменил???

Comment: Да я просто и менял, но были ошибки

Comment: Если без класса Investment, то просто в deposit добавляете первый параметр self и рекурсивный вызов делаете как `self.deposit(...)` вместо просто `deposit(...)`. В каком-то дополнительном классе Investment для хранения параметров особой необходимости нет, это только усложнит код.

Comment: Необходимо с классом Investment, как без него - это первый вариант кода

Comment: @Beger для чего конкретно нужен класс Investment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
class Investment:

    def __init__(self, N, R):
        self.N = N
        self.R = R
        self.Month = 12 * self.R


class Bank:

    def deposit(self, n, month):
        if month == 0:
            return n
        return self.deposit(n, month - 1) * (1 + 10 / 100 / 12)


bank = Bank()
vklad = Investment(14, 10)
print(bank.deposit(vklad.N, vklad.Month))
```